# In express when i call next(err) the next tick/middleware does not get called/processed

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, routes, middleware

This is a cool little middleware that returns a 405 error if the req.url  matches one of the other routes connected to the same router object.

If it finds a match it will check to see if there is a matching http verb if there is no matching http verb it will set the flag to true and trigger the error.

My problem is that when `next(err)` gets called the next tick does not  get processed. The server just blows up with an error as if i actually  threw one.

I want the next tick to be processed (which is my error handeling middleware).

**start.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

//Other routes

router.use( function(req, res, next) {

    var flag = false;
    for (var i = 0, rl = router.stack.length; i < rl; i++) {
      var route = router.stack[i].route;
      if (route && req.url.toLowerCase() === route.path.toLowerCase()) {
        for (var method in route.methods) {
          if (route.methods.hasOwnProperty(method)) {
            if(method.toLowerCase() !== req.method.toLowerCase()){
              flag = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
    if (flag) {
      var err = new Error('Method Not Allowed');
      err.status = 405;
      return next(err);
    }

    return next();
});
module.exports = router
```

#### EDIT:

**routes.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();


router.use(require('../middlewares/successHandler_logger'));

router.use('/start', require('./start/start'));
router.use('/login', require('./login/login'));

router.use(require('../middlewares/errorHandeling'));


module.exports = router
```

**errorHandler.js**

```
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router();

router.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  err.status = err.status || 500;
  if (!err.json) {
    err.json = {
      status:err.status,
      success: false,
      message: 'oops',
    }
  };


  res.status(err.status).json(err.json);

  console.log(err.stack);

});
module.exports = router
```

Comment: Similar example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28679983/why-does-this-node-js-callback-not-run-immediately/28680492#28680492

Comment: That thread says that it should work as i expect, by running the next event handler in the queue. But sadly it is not.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your middleware is in the right order and installed properly?  If you put a `console.log()` in your other middleware is it called at all?

Comment: I can ```console.log``` before and within this middleware, and if i don't send the err with the next call it will pass to my error handler just fine. EG: ```return next(/*err*/);```

Comment: Can you show us the error handling middleware?  It might be helpful to read [this article](https://blog.safaribooksonline.com/2014/03/12/error-handling-express-js-applications/).  Is your error handling middleware declared with four arguments as shown in the examples?

Comment: There is some context. My error middleware does have 4 args.

Comment: I don't follow how all your modules are using the same `router`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71898/discussion-between-codenamejames-and-jfriend00).

Comment: Ive updated the question. I call express in each file and define a new router and then export it at the end.

Comment: `express.Router()` creates a new router.  I think your middleware is perhaps not working the way you want because each is defined on a different router and you're then doing `router.use(routerX)` rather than `router.use(handler)`.  You can devise a way to share the same router.

Comment: Why not make `errorHandler.js` just export its handler?  It doesn't need its own router because the user of the module already has a router.  I think that perhaps the error handling with `next(err)` that you want doesn't work across routers.

Comment: You are correct it worked :-) if you answer i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have multiple routers and the error handling chaining you want does not work across routers.

I'd suggest you only create one router and share it.  For example, in `errorHandler.js`, you can do this:

```
module.exports = function(err, req, res, next) {
  err.status = err.status || 500;
  if (!err.json) {
    err.json = {
      status:err.status,
      success: false,
      message: 'oops',
    }
  };


  res.status(err.status).json(err.json);

  console.log(err.stack);

});
```

And, then this will still work:

```
router.use(require('../middlewares/errorHandeling'));
```

You would then similarly have to use one common router in the other places.

Comment: Ok so i kept my routes on a different router and its working just as long as my error handler is not in its own router. So i guess the errors can bubble up but not down routers. Good to know.